# Google analytics and django datetime

Tags: django, datetime, google-analytics

I am trying to club together the data from google analytics and django application.

The datetime of django in database are in UTC. Google analytics data has timezone as IST.

I am getting data from google analytics for a period based on IST and getting data from django for same period in IST. There are lot of variations .

- Is there any way this can be solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option here could be to change the default timezone from your Django App to IST.

First of all you should check [Django settings: TIME_ZONE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE)

You will understand better how to fix it if you understand how it works.

To change the default timezone to IST you need to add in your **settings.py**:

```
TIME_ZONE =  'Asia/Kolkata'
```

If `Asia/Kolkata` doesn't fit your needs, you can check all the available time zones in the next URL:

[List of Time Zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

If you prefer to manage the datetime objects and convert from UTC to IST or viceversa you can do it like this:

## Convert data from UTC to IST

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"

# Current time in UTC
now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
print now_utc.strftime(format)
Output: 2015-05-18 10:02:47 UTC+0000

# Convert to Asia/Kolkata time zone
now_asia = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
print now_asia.strftime(format)
Output: 2015-05-18 15:32:47 IST+0530
```

## Convert data from IST to UTC

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"

# Current time in Asia/Kolkata
now_asia = datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
print now_asia.strftime(format)
Output: 2015-05-18 15:32:47 IST+0530

# Convert to UTC time zone
now_utc = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('UTC'))
print now_utc.strftime(format)
Output: 2015-05-18 10:02:47 UTC+0000
```

Answer (score 0):

IST (Indian Standard Time) is 5:30 ahead of UTC (http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist). When getting data from Django, make sure that you use localized datetime objects:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime    

tz_india = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
start = tz_india.localize(datetime(#Here create you datetime object from IST))
end = tz_india.localize(datetime(#Here create you datetime object from IST))
```